# What resources are useful to build framework with API like Facebook?

Tags: .net, design-patterns, architecture

We will develop a web site that will have some free services and we want to make it as a framework that can any build application over it or can use its API in their site.

Could any lead me in how to start it, what's the better architecture and design pattern help in that, is there any resources discuss or explain how to do like this ?

We are dot net developers but we can learn any other if it's needed in such a solution.

Comment: This was probably on-topic in 2010, but now it would be regarded as Too Broad or Opinion Based, and thus should probably be put on hold.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best thing I can suggest would be to use Domain Driven Design and architecture to develop a system that would expose your api as domains that can be programmed.

Comment: are you try such one and you see it's a good one or just from reading about ?

Comment: We do a lot of DDD and specifically to create api that the user can use to write applications within our architecture.